# SQL Server 2005 Date Range

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to run a query on a specific date range for my company's fiscal year, which ends in October.

The query needs to run from October 1 of the last year through the current date, but if the current year gets past October, then it needs to switch over to October of this year.

So: currently it would be October 1, 2013 to July 16, 2014.

Starting on October 2, 2014 it will be October 2, 2014 to October 2, 2014.

I could simply go in and change the SQL every October, but I figured there was an easier way to do this with a logic statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you put in any effort yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:

```
SELECT 
   <your_column_list> 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE
    date_col >= CASE
                  WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) < 10 THEN CAST(('1.10.' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1 as CHAR(4)) AS DATETIME)
                  ELSE GETDATE()
                END
    AND
    date_col < CASE 
                   WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) < 10 THEN GETDATE()
                   ELSE
                        CAST(('1.10.' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1 as CHAR(4)) AS DATETIME)
               END
```

I'm not sure about the exact dates, i don't get the october 2nd part. You will have to adjust the date format as well. I used dd.mm.yyyy on your system it might be different.

Answer (score 0):

So this should be giving the desired results.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, 
      @endDate DATETIME, 
      @today DATETIME;

BEGIN

   SET @today = CONVERT(DATETIME, '03/1/14');

   SELECT @startDate = CASE
                WHEN MONTH(@today) < 10 THEN '10/01/' + LTRIM(STR(YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @today))))
                WHEN MONTH(@today) = 10
                 AND MONTH(@today) = 1 THEN '10/01/' + LTRIM(STR(YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @today))))
                WHEN MONTH(@today) = 10
                 AND MONTH(@today) > 1 THEN '10/01/' + LTRIM(STR(YEAR(@today)))
                WHEN MONTH(@today) > 10 THEN '10/01/' + LTRIM(STR(YEAR(@today)))
                    ELSE '1/1/2000'
                END,
        @endDate = GETDATE();

   SELECT @startDate, @endDate;

END;
```